# Transparent image shows white on bootstrap button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, css-selectors, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add facebook login button without icon library. by using the Facebook icon image with transparent background while it shows completely white.
Here is the code:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-image btn-soc form-btn btn-lg btn-block">ign In  With Facebook</button>
```

**css**

```
.btn-image:before {
    content: "";
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-position : center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-image: url('../../../assets/social-icons/facebook.png');


}
```

When I try to add background: none and border: none it disappears completely.
So what is wrong how can I make the icon show normally?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you replicate your problem in a code snippet ? From a first look adding `background: none` of course will hide your image

Comment: At the moment the only code is above HTML and CSS and it shows white rectangle inside the button. while the image has a transparent background and there icon should be visible instead of that white background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the white square you see is the white part of the letter "F" of "facebook", but since it is so big, you only see a white square.

Try putting a `background-size: 100%` on `btn-image`.